# Is there something that improves the c++ interpreter built in to Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm going to school for computer programming and I have been using Xcode and really like its predictive text input (or whatever you call it maybe interpreter). The only thing is that it seems to function a little different when creating a C++ project. Such as you don't have to say "#include " to use the string library. Where as in Visual Studio you have to. What i'm afraid of is turning in a class project done on Xcode and missing including a lib and losing points. So i would like to do it on VS 2010 but i would like to have a better interpreter. Any help on this.

Comment: You've mentioned vague "improvement" without being specific. Are you having a problem with Visual Studio? If so, what is it?

Comment: The interpreter for C++ in visual studio isn't very good. For instance when i type

Comment: disregard above   The interpreter for C++ in visual studio isn't very good. For instance when i type #inc i could like to see a pop for all the possible c++ words i could us. As i type more of the word it narrows down the chooses. Visual Studio does some of this but it's not as robust as Xcode. Also the text highlighting leaves some to be desired. It doesn't highlight the say a member function of a class differently. I just wanted to know if there is some sort of third party add-on or official add-on that improves this for the C++ language.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean AutoComplete.....  and there is an add on called Visual Assist X that makes it magic for C++ coding.